# How to use react components inside handlebar templates of a NestJs based MVC application

Tags: reactjs, nestjs, handlebars.js

I'm building a simple web application with **NestJS**. I'm following the MVC pattern (Need not add more complexity with the backend frontend approach).

What is the best way to include a few **react** components inside the **handlebar** template files?

My current directory structure is as follows. Any lead to get it done is really appreciated.

[image]